# How do I pull a User object based on the attribute of a model it is associated with?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

My template generates a URL that is: `/user/username` for example: `/user/tainawilkins`

```
<a href="user/{{ user.userprofile.slug }}"
style="color:rgba(0,0,200,1.00)">{{ user.username }} {{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}</a>
```

and it invokes this view:

```
def user(request, user_name_slug):

    context_dict = {}

    try:
        # Can we find a city name slug with the given name?
        # If we can't, the .get() method raises a DoesNotExist exception.
        # So the .get() method returns one model instance or raises an exception.
        user = User.objects.select_related('UserProfile').get(slug=user_name_slug)
        context_dict['user_username'] = user.username
        context_dict['user_firstname'] = user.first_name
        context_dict['user_secondname'] = user.second_name

        context_dict['user'] = user
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        pass

    # Go render the response and return it to the client.
    return render(request, 'user.html', context_dict)
```

The User model is the django built-in model and this is the UserProfile:

```
# this is model for user
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    profilepic = models.ImageField(blank=True)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.user.username)
        super(UserProfile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username

    @property
    def avg_rating(User):
        return UserProfile.userrating_set.all().aggregate(Avg('rating'))['rating__avg']
```

My main problem is with this line in views.py that I can't get it to work. I want to pull the User by specifying the slug of the UserProfile (one to one relationship):

```
    user = User.objects.select_related('UserProfile').get(slug=user_name_slug)
```

I receive this error:

> FieldError at /user/tainawilkins Cannot resolve keyword 'slug' into
>   field. Choices are: date_joined, email, first_name, groups, hobby, id,
>   is_active, is_staff, is_superuser, language, last_login, last_name,
>   logentry, password, registrationprofile, user_permissions, username,
>   userprofile, userrating

Answer (score 2):

In general I recommend explicitly giving a `related_name` to the `OneToOneField`, e.g.: `user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')`. Without it, by default, the related name is `userprofile` as you can see from the error message.

You can query it using the `<related_field_name>__<field_name_on_related_lookup>` field lookup syntax, i.e.:

`user = User.objects.select_related('UserProfile').get(profile__slug=user_name_slug)`

Learn more at [Lookups that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)